# Golang package - go-logging

Tags: go

I am trying to use the golang package: https://github.com/op/go-logging

I have set it up following the instructions and it works.

```
var log = logging.MustGetLogger("example")

var format = logging.MustStringFormatter(
    "%{color}%{time:15:04:05.000} %{shortfunc} ▶ %{level:.4s} %{id:03x}%{color:reset} %{message}",
)

func main() {

    backend2 := logging.NewLogBackend(os.Stderr, "", 0)
    backend2Formatter := logging.NewBackendFormatter(backend2, format)
    logging.SetBackend(backend2Formatter)

    log.Info("info")
    log.Notice("notice")
    log.Warning("warning")
    log.Error("err")
    log.Critical("crit")

    r.POST("/v1.0/route-one/", controllers.RouteOne)
    r.GET("/v1.0/route-two", controllers.RouteTwo)

    r.Run(":8080")

}
```

However I want to create logs from any of the controllers from within my App, how would I create logs from within a controller after the initial declaration in main.go without having to re-write the format etc? Ideally id like to be able to just write `log.Error("err")` anywhere to create a log.

**UPDATE**

Created a package:

```
package log

import (
    "github.com/op/go-logging"
    "os"
)

var Log = logging.MustGetLogger("example")

var format = logging.MustStringFormatter(
    "%{color}%{time:15:04:05.000} %{shortfunc} ▶ %{level:.4s} %{id:03x}%{color:reset} %{message}",
)

func init() {

    backend2 := logging.NewLogBackend(os.Stderr, "", 0)
    backend2Formatter := logging.NewBackendFormatter(backend2, format)
    logging.SetBackend(backend2Formatter)

    Log.Info("info")
    Log.Notice("notice")
    Log.Warning("warning")
    Log.Error("err")
    Log.Critical("crit")
}
```

Then tried to add it into my controller by importing and running `Log.Error("test")` but I get the error of `undefined: Log in Log.Error`

Comment: Write a package, expose your configured logger. Import that package in your controllers.

Comment: @thwd So I have made a package called log. Invoked the logging code inside a function called "init()" then imported in my controller ` _ "github.com/MediaMath/apps_api/log"` but I get the error of `undefined: log in log.Error` when I try and invoke, any ideas? - Updated Question

Comment: In your second example, `var log` is inside `main()`'s scope. It should be a global variable (with uppercase first letter) for it to be access of outside of `main` and the package itself.

Comment: @Nadh Updated again, similar error

Comment: Importing with `_` omits the package's identifiers. I think you want `import . "github.com/blablabla/log"`

Comment: @thwd Thanks for the help, missed the extra log off! Working!